# Exporting the results of an Access 2013 select query into an Excel 2013 sheet without creating a new worksheet or breaking references

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

This problem is fairly simple but it's baffling me, especially since this code works perfectly fine in a different application I have made, so I suspect there is some hidden setting somewhere that's causing the problem.

I need to transfer the results of an Access select query into a copy of a template Excel sheet. This template has a few other sheets in it that refer to the sheet that will receive the Access query data, which then do some formatting and calculations with it. All I need is for this single query's results to be transferred to the correct sheet, with no formatting or anything. Overwriting the whole sheet is fine too.

My problem is that, instead of copying to the sheet "qryLineItemsExportBuffer", it creates a *new* sheet, named "qryLineItemsExportBuffer1" and puts the query results there - so all the references in the workbook are looking in the wrong place. I also cannot use the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet [Range] parameter to define a destination sheet, [because this does not work when exporting, only while importing.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793(v=office.15).aspx)

Here is my code - it 1. opens the template, 2. saves a copy with a new name, 3. transfers the query result, and then 4. opens the copy and recalculates/rebuilds links:

```vb
Private Sub cmdExportInvoiceRequestForm_Click()

Dim instExcelTemplate As Object
Dim xlsxInvoiceRequestTemplate As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsxInvoiceRequestNewName As String
Dim xlsxInvoiceRequestCopy As Excel.Workbook

    xlsxInvoiceRequestNewName = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & CustomerName & "-InvoiceRequest-" & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx" 'create the name for the new invoice report
    MsgBox xlsxInvoiceRequestNewName 'user is shown the name and date
    MsgBox Application.CurrentProject.Path 'user is shown the destination folder

    'start an Excel instance and open the template workbook.
    Set instExcelTemplate = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlsxInvoiceRequestTemplate = instExcelTemplate.Workbooks.Open(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Templates\CustomerInvoiceRequestFormTemplate.xlsx") 'open the invoice report template
    xlsxInvoiceRequestTemplate.SaveAs FileName:=(xlsxInvoiceRequestNewName) 'save the template as a new file in the correct directory
    instExcelTemplate.Workbooks.Close 'close the Excel instance.

    'transfer the qryLineItemsExportBuffer results to the newly created workbook.
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "qryLineItemsExportBuffer", xlsxInvoiceRequestNewName
    'start an excel instance and open the new workbook.
    Set instExcelCopy = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlsxInvoiceRequestCopy = instExcelCopy.Workbooks.Open(xlsxInvoiceRequestNewName)
    instExcelCopy.CalculateFullRebuild 'recalculate all values and rebuild links in the workbook. This is necessary because it does not do this when opened manually. Can be done in Excel with CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+F9.
    xlsxInvoiceRequestCopy.Save 'save the copy
    instExcelCopy.Workbooks.Close 'close the Excel instance.
    Set xlsxInvoiceRequestCopy = Nothing
    Set instExcelCopy = Nothing
    xlsxInvoiceRequestNewName = ""


End Sub
```

I also cannot put any code into the Excel template itself, so I can't make it copy the data over from the new sheet.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a thought - does your template already contain a (perhaps hidden) sheet called "qryLineItemsExportBuffer"?

Comment: It does contain a blank sheet with that name, yes. It must do so, because the other sheets in the workbook template have formulas which refer to the sheet, anticipating the input of data there. I cannot have those references without such a sheet present, however, otherwise I'll get #REF! errors.

Comment: Oh yes, how stupid of me! In that case I'm guessing that there must be some switch that determines whether your code tries to add data to an existing sheet or create a new sheet. You say you already have this working in another application. Is it the same versions of Access/Excel? Can you try substituting elements of the non-working system into the working one and vice versa to see whether the problem is with your Access code or the Excel template?

Comment: Hmm. So I had already tried making a blank template with the named sheet, and changing the name, and none of that worked. However, what did work just now was using the Excel template from the other application! It overwrites into the sheet correctly rather than making a new one. So I'm looking through the old template trying to figure out where the difference in setting is, and cannot find it. I will keep looking.

Comment: I kept digging deeper into the template sheet for the previous application - it turned out that there was a Excel named range that had the same name as the destination sheet and the generating query - so I had not noticed that it was exporting to the named range, not the sheet name or the query name! Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Great news, glad you found it. That's actually something I could use myself. I have previously got around this by assuming Access will create the new sheet; I then have code in my Excel 'template' that looks for the new sheet, copies the data from this new sheet to a known location on a previously existing sheet (where all my references point to) and then deleting the new sheet. Next time this instance of the workbook is opened the new sheet doesn't exist any more so there's nothing to do.

Comment: Yes, that's how I would have otherwise done it, but for end-user reasons I could not include any code in the Excel file itself.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the correct way to use the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method to export the results of Access queries to a specific sheet or range in an Excel worksheet, without creating new sheets. [The documentation for this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793(v=office.15).aspx) strongly suggests that you cannot set a Range parameter for exports to Excel from Access, and I have not found any other sources online which mention this capability. But in fact, you can effectively set a destination range for DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet by using Excel's Name Manager.

Let's say we want to transfer the results of Access query 'qryItemsExport' to a sheet in a workbook, named 'DestinationWorkbook.xlsx', in the same folder as the Access database.

First, go into the workbook's name manager and set a named range called 'qryItemsExport' where you'd like the data to go. Then, use the following VBA in the Access project:

```
Dim xlsxDestinationWorkbook as String

xlsxDestinationWorkbook = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "DestinationWorkbook.xlsx"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qryItemsExport", xlsxDestinationWorkbook
```

The first line declares the workbook name variable as a string. The second line assigns the workbook name variable to the version currently in the same folder as the Access project. The third line exports the data from the query to the destination workbook, for an Excel 2010+ format. Because the command attempts to export to the destination 'qryItemsExport', this goes to the previously named range and places the data in that location, starting in the upper-left-hand-corner. It does not create new sheets or rename existing ones, so references to the sheet being copied to will stay intact.